# How do I get Google refund orders ？

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, google-developers-console

The [Google Void Purchase API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases) says:

> The Google Play Voided Purchases API allows you to revoke access to
>   in-app products that are associated with purchases that a user has
>   voided. The user can void a purchase in the following ways:
>
> - The user requests a refund for their order.
> - The user cancels their order.
> - An order is charged back.

But when I  get this API's return, I found some purchases state are Charged.

Why Charged order is return by Google Void Purchases ?

How do I get all refund orders ?

Comment: Having the same problem here. Refunded orders are not returned by voided purchases API, which kinda defeats its whole purpose. I don't know if this a bug or a feature, and I also don't know who to ask, because Google Play console provides ZERO means to contact tech support.

Comment: +1 I'd like a definite answer - I've always assumed subscriptions that get refunded will return "not-purchased" the next time the app checks, but actually I have no idea and no idea how to check single purchases

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get the way to handle this, that is , recheck from google.

Just like when the purchase is paid, we check from google is this purchase really paid, and if we get a return from Void Purchase, we can use paid API
get the purchase STATE, if not CHARGED, I think the purchase is real void purchase, hope this help.

Comment: So you are "polling" every order for its status? That is not effective, especially that the time during which user can refund the order is virtually unlimited, so with the course of time the number of polled orders will be growing indefinitely.

Comment: No, A user can refund his order is not  virtually unlimited, google will auto refund just in a few hours.

Comment: I am not "polling" all orders, I just polling the orders that created  in a few hours.    This is a way.
The another way is that  get void data from the Google Void Purchase, and 
check the purchase status by what you get.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer, perhaps provide a example how to implement it?

Comment: Google has fixed this bug in the latest API. Just send a request to  GET the The data of Google Play Voided Purchases API and check the Purchases state is ok.

Comment: Add a new [API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications) is created.